# Forms authentication config shows windows authentication dialog box, why?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership, forms-authentication

Why does a windows authentication dialog box show on my asp.net application? I have included my web.config in a pastebin:

http://pastebin.com/iRzsFgsr

Any help is appreciated I have forms authentication enabled and anonymous but its not going through as expected. Thanks

Comment: Having exactly the same problem right now. All my other sites work, but this one site is just giving me the damn windows authentication box. I'm ready to throw the server out of the window - works fine in my development environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have it set as `Windows Authentication` in `IIS` or your page is accessing something the `IUSR` account doesn't have permission to on the file system.

Set you app pool to a more privileged account and see if it happens, if not then you know it's the `IUSR` permissions.

Comment: i do not i have it set as forms autentication

Comment: I have the same problem and this does not solve the problem for me either

Answer (score 0):

Not much to go on, but IIRC that can happen when a page (including apps configured to use forms authentication) is trying to access a resource specified by a UNC path/network share. You might want to check, and if that *is* the problem, Google how to map a UNC to an IIS virtual directory.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your site allows anonymous access and if IUSR_TEMPLATE (or whichever user/group you use) has access to root directory of your site.